# Redux action creator syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
function addTodoWithDispatch(text) {
  const action = {
    type: ADD_TODO,
    text
  }
  dispatch(action)
}
```

http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html#action-creators

I saw the code above from redux documentation. What I don't understand is the `text` in the `action`. It doesn't look like a valid javascript object or array syntax. Is it an ES6 new syntax? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please give the link to the document? From your example, it does not look like a valid javascript object.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. Updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

It is just a new [ES6 syntax](https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand), which simplifies creating properties on the literal syntax

In short, if the name is the same as the property, you only have to write it once

So this would be exactly the same :)

```
function addTodoWithDispatch(text) {
  const action = {
    type: ADD_TODO,
    text: text
  }
  dispatch(action)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the above code

```
function addTodoWithDispatch(text) {
  const action = {
    type: ADD_TODO,
    text
  }
  dispatch(action)
}
```

here `text` is an example of object literal shorthand notation. ES6 gives you a shortcut for defining properties on an object whose value is equal to another variable with the same key.

As has been said this is just shorthand for writing

```
const action = {
    type: ADD_TODO,
    text: text
  }
  dispatch(action)
```

Have a look at this **[blog](http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/)**

Comment: @Aprillion I did not notice, I will delete the other one, thanks for reminding

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the next page in document http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html

```
function todoApp(state = initialState, action) {
 switch (action.type) {
  case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    visibilityFilter: action.filter
  })
 case ADD_TODO:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    todos: [
      ...state.todos,
      {
        text: action.text,
        completed: false
      }
    ]
  })
case TOGGLE_TODO:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    todos: state.todos.map((todo, index) => {
      if(index === action.index) {
        return Object.assign({}, todo, {
          completed: !todo.completed
        })
      }
      return todo
    })
  })
default:
  return state
 }
}
```

It is expecting property name text. As @Icepickle mentioned it is a valid format but you can also change to below format:

```
function addTodoWithDispatch(text) {
  const action = {
     type: ADD_TODO,
     text:text
   }
  dispatch(action)
}
```

Comment: @ElgsQianChen I can't see who downvoted so I was asking to the person who gave it a downvote.

Comment: You are not explaining it correctly, the syntax in his code is completely correct (see the other 2 responses), it's a new object shorthand literal syntax in ES6. It is true you could write it as you suggest, but there is originally nothing wrong with the code, so your suggestion is mute (especially if you use arrow functions / spread syntax also introduced in ES6). In short, your answer doesn't bring anything new, and doesn't respond to the question itself

Comment: @Icepickle Thank you for your comment. Good to know.

Comment: @vishalpatel Nothing is stopping you to either edit your answer to make it a good one which adds something the other 2 answer do not add, or to remove it (except maybe the +6 rep points from getting 1 upvote (+10) and 2 downvotes (-4))